# Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

hi i started new project and run command ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0 --save
and i got this error
Adding android project…
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
Path: platforms\android
Package: com.ipe.yogaclass
Name: Yoga_Class_App
Activity: MainActivity
Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png
detail its showing like package name and name are wrong its showing details of other app
it was working fine before some days please help me in this regard help will be appreciated its also showing wrong package name i am building on other project please help me in this regard

Comment: First things first: Does the file  resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png exist?

Comment: yes it have in folder

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to generate them?

1. First you have to place your icon.png and splash.png under resources/ folder.
2. Make sure the images have the suggested dimensions:
   "The source image for icons should ideally be at least 1024×1024px and located at resources/icon.png. The source image for splash screens should ideally be at least 2732×2732px and located at resources/splash.png."
3. Run the command `ionic cordova resources ios` or `ionic cordova resources android`, depending on the platform you want to build.

Comment: ionic cordova resources android
√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

? Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it? (Y/n) y
? Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

Comment: Adding android project...
        Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
                Path: platforms\android
                Package: com.ipe.yogaclass
                Name: Yoga_Class_App
                Activity: MainActivity
                Android target: android-25
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
        Error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png

Answer (score 1):

I get same error. I fixed calling `ionic cordova run`. Then all resource files were regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still looking at this. I fixed the issue by removing all the lines regarding '/resources/' within my .gitignore file.  On new Ionic application creations, they're adding the resources folder to the .gitignore file by default.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your icon and save it with an extension of ".png", not ".PNG". In your case, save it as drawable-hdpi-icon.png.

To check if it is saved as .png or .PNG, right-click the icon and hit Properties. Under General tab, check if it is:

Type of file: PNG File (.png)
or
Type of file: PNG File (.PNG)